# Restrict user from accessing any web page without login

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I want any user to be restricted if they are not logged in.
suppose if they try to access any page by pasting the link still they are redirected to login page.

**LoginPage**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employee where UName =@username and UPassword=@password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", UPassword.Text);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `<allow>` section in `web.config` can help you:

```
<!--Deny access for 'images' folder-->
<location path="images">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/> <!--A question mark (?) denies anonymous users-->
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<!--Will deny anonymous users for all pages-->
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

More about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i dont want to restrict each folder seperately.

Comment: So you can use second snippet (with `<deny users="?"/>` for all pages).

Comment: how do i know that the user is authenticated ? without session

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through session in asp.net:

Create a session after the successful login of the user like as follows

**Login Page:**

Include the below namespace.

`using System.Web.SessionState;`

after user entered the user name and password:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employee where UName =@username and UPassword=@password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", UPassword.Text);

    //Blah,Blah,Blah...
 if(user=authenticated user) //your condition goes here
   {
       session["Sid"]=Session.SessionID;
       //Blah,Blah,Blah...
   }
```

Now in every page which you want to secure should have this follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["Sid"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

            }
        }
```

In **web.config**:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="120" />
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Is this the traditional way in asp.net ? Any other good way, without session ?